# jQuery mobile 1.1RC - using the loader/spinner in header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to use the jQuery mobile 1.1 loader/spinner in the header (in addition to the standard dialog shown when loading pages). The visibility of the loader in the header is toggled in javascript, displayed when syncing/downloading application cache.

Does anyone know how I can create a new instance of the loader/spinner for my custom use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the sound of your idea and have been fighting spinners for a few days now.

I took the liberty of making a jsFiddle for you.

Is [this kinda what you had in mind?](http://jsfiddle.net/F36KJ/2/)

You would have to extend jQueryMobile and add a method the fires up this secondary loader.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to find your custom JS in the example

Comment: Terribly sorry my good sir I have updated the link accordingly